# I just upgraded my RAM and still running slow. Can I add Mem from Swap?

Tags: ram, memory-usage

I have two slots of RAM, 4 GB and 8 GB (just added). But, it runs like it has 4 GB only (just like before it's upgraded). I try to monitor my memory usage with `free -h`, and this is the condition:
[Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzTBL.png). Is there something wrong? Or can I add more Mem from the Swap?

Comment: Adding swap isn't the same as adding additional memory.  If a required page isn't in ram but was written to swap, a process will need to pause as used memory is written to swap, and the required pages are retrieved from swap and returned to ram. There is also overhead with swap (ie. the system has to check if the page is in memory, or needs to be retrieved from swap), so not having enough RAM, but too much swap can cause overhead to lower performance, not increase it.  Yes adding swap can improve performance, but in other circumstances it'll reduce performance (the fix being adding real ram)

Comment: It maybe I'm confused, if you're talking about your machine only recognizing a single ram module, I'd not boot the OS until your machine BIOS/UEFI has detected the RAM. Some machines do actually require RAM to match up, in fact they all have their own quirks, if this is your issue, it's a hardware issue and the OS is not involved.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should not post [screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your post and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). However, it really looks like the system has not detected the added RAM module. Unfortunately, this is a hardware issue that is off-topic here.

Comment: Only 4GBs is being seen/used.  Could be a few things, but first would remove new ram and put it back in.  Also check if new ram is for your computer, same specs as old ram.

Comment: Before booting Ubuntu, first check that your BIOS detects the extra memory. If not, the two memory modules may not be compatible.  As a last resort you can remove the old 4GB and leave only the new 8 GB.